# MVC vs Webforms: getting data from page to code behind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

Using webforms, a control can be defined like this:

```
<asp:label id="lblDate" runat="server"></asp:label>
```

and the code behind can manipulate it like this:

```
    lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + " eheheh";
    lblDate.ToolTip = "tooltip";
    lblDate.BackColor = Color.Red;
...
```

My question is: is there a similar way to manipulate a control in MVC?

Comment: You should start by reading basic introduction to MVC. MVC has no controls, it has models (or viewmodels) and HTML helpers in views. You can manipulate html properties any way you want, but you should do it in view, not in controller.

Comment: @dotnetom, imagine this scenario: I want to press a button that clears a textbox, for example. Should I use `Javascript` to do it exclusively or can I do it by using the controller?

Comment: Any simple manipulations (like clearing the textbox) that do not require any information processing on server in my opinion should always be done on client side. Even if you need simple processing on server it often makes sense to make an AJAX call to server and process the results. The benefits are that you send much less data over the network, the UI remains more responsive and user friendly. In case of web forms there is an easy (too easy) way to manipulate UI elements from server side, so this can be misused.

Answer (score 1):

MVC doesn't have server control; instead, it has [HtmlHelper](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/N50P050314-Understanding-HTML-Helpers-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html).

For example, the following [Label Helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310185%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) will generate the similar HTML mark up redered by WebForm's label control.

```
@Html.Label("Date", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), 
   new { style = "background-color: red", title="this is tooltip" })
```

Comment: ok but could I access that label in the controller by writing something like `Date.Text = "whatever"`? Because writing the HTML isn't the issue, even for a non experienced HTML developer, finding the syntax is easy, even the intellisense can help with that. The issue is manipulating the labels, textboxes, buttons, etc.. Like in the code behind we have in Webforms

Comment: `could I access that label in the controller` the answer is no. You cannot access it directly; instead, you need to create it using Model. [Adam Freeman's Pro ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-Experts-Voice-ASP-Net/dp/1430265299/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1403100331&sr=8-1&keywords=asp.net+mvc) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing will be for you to use JS or HTML tags while you can do it in the controller it is kinda pointless and too much work for basic properties you could use Ajax for that but like i said too  much work. For Clearing textbox use JS. There are things like controls which are essentially JS libraries that have a corresponding .Net Libraries and you can build objects for the view and control them from Controller, usually those are for advanced and more rich features you add to your web site.